# filter words on a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have a string in which all of the beginning of every word are capitalized. Now i want to filter it like if it can detect words link "as, the, of, in, etc" it will be converted to lower cases. I have a code that replace and convert it to lower case, but for 1 word only like below:

```
$str = "This Is A Sample String Of Hello World";
$str = preg_replace('/\bOf\b/', 'of', $str);

output: This Is A Sample String of Hello World
```

So what i want is that to filter other words such as on the string like "is, a". Its odd to repeat the preg_replace for every word to filter.

Thanks!

Comment: ... it's also odd to combine all the words into one regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$str = "This Is A Sample String Of Hello World";
$str = ucfirst(preg_replace_callback(
       '/\b(Of|Is|A)\b/',
       create_function(
           '$matches',
           'return strtolower($matches[0]);'
       ),
       $str
   ));
echo $str;
```

[Displays "This is a Sample String of Hello World".](http://codepad.org/uqamuPiA)

Comment: But... it will murder those 3 words if they are the start of a sentence. http://codepad.org/EGzKj1E3

Comment: That's easily fixed by running [ucfirst()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php).

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the exact word and format you should be using [str_replace](http://us.php.net/str_replace) rather than preg_replace; it's much faster.

```
$text = str_replace(array('Is','Of','A'),array('is','of','a'),$text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$words = array('Of', 'Is', 'A', 'The');  // Add more words here

echo preg_replace_callback('/\b('.implode('|', $words).')\b/', function($m) {
    return strtolower($m[0]);
}, $str);


// This is a Sample String of Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$replace = array(
'dog' => 'cat',
'apple' => 'orange',
'chevy' => 'ford'
 );

$string = 'I like to eat an apple with my dog in my chevy';
function strReplaceAssoc(array $replace, $subject) {
    return str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace),     $subject);   
}
echo strReplaceAssoc($replace,$string);
```